# Issue using chrome tabs api, can't use chrome.tabs.move

Tags: google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

So, originally I was trying to use the chrome tabs api on my new tab extension, (which has the tabs permission) in order to move the current tab one space backward (to the left), When I tried entering chrome.tabs.move(with all my data in here), it said no matching signature

I have tried playing around with console logging and rereading the api page

Here is the API Page: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-move

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(
     function(currentTab){
          chrome.tabs.move(currentTab.id, currentTab.index-1);
     }
);
```

I expected it to run and the current tab to moved but I got this message:

index.html:1 Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.move([integer|array] tabIds, object moveProperties, optional function callback): No matching signature.
    at :3:23

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `chrome.tabs.move()` function incorrectly.

As documented on the page you linked, the second argument must be an object containing `index` and (optionally) `windowId` properties, e.g.

```
chrome.tabs.move(currentTab.id, { 'index': currentTab.index - 1 })
```